# Error when I install autoviz on anaconda prompt

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I have been trying to install autoviz but every time I try to I get this error message: Failed to build worldcloud and ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1
[Failed to build worldcloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swMoG.jpg)

Can anyone help with this issue.

On a side note I am new to python and I am not sure how/or the best est way to install packages and modules on python so if anyone has any references that are easy to read and helpful I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

According to its [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/wordcloud/), `wordcloud` is available as a wheel for several platforms.

As for anaconda, it says:

> If you are using conda, you can install from the `conda-forge channel`:
>
> `conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud`

Otherwise, you'll have to build it yourself. Which on ms-windows means you'll have to install a C compiler and tools. While not intrinsically difficult, this can be intimidating for people who are new to building C-extensions for Python modules.